# use a random generated number in 2 methods and call random generator again

Tags: java, loops, object, random

I will try to explain this as good as possible. I have 2 methods that both use a number between 1 and 4 generated by a random generator object. I made the random generator object outside both methods but I need to generate a new number, use it in one method and use that same number generated in another method then, generate another number to to the same process. but I cant get how I can Generate a number outside both methods, use it in both methods, and then generate another number to use in both methods. It will be used turn by turn in both methods.

Comment: You could seed the RNG to the same seed in each method?

Comment: how would i do that

Comment: @z123 Look through Java's `Random` class documentation. Look for something that mentions seeding it. Looking through the documentation to find things you need is a critical skill that you need to develop.

Comment: "I will try to explain this as good as possible". You did not do a very good job if you don't have code posted.

Answer (score 0):

So firstly, if both of the methods are called from the same method you can simply pass the random number generated to each method as a parameter. However, you can reach a similar effect without calling both of the methods at the same time. You can do this by using two separate `Random` objects seeded to the same value. So you would do something like

```
long seed = System.currentTimeMillis();
Random randa;
Random randb;
```

And then in the constructor that creates the `Random` object do the following

```
randa = new Random(seed);
randb = new Random(seed);
```

Then simply call randa in one function and randb in the other.

Comment: But one method is going to run before the other therefore the milliseconds change changing the end result. I need both of them to have the same value

Comment: You assign the seed outside of both of the methods. As long as the seed is set outside of the methods, and both rands are intialized with it, they will generate numbers exactly the same. Furthermore, the seed does not have to be the time, I simply am using that as am example as that is a common seed. It could be generated each time using a separate RNG or even hard coded into the program.